# ipython always displaying object information. How to disable?

Tags: ipython

Ipython is always displaying object identifiers after I press enter.

e.g.

```
In[6]: fig = plt.figure()
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x10b8666d0>


In[7]: figure();
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x10b860650>
```

Is there any way to disable this behavior?

This is using IPython 1.1.0 and Python 2.7.6 on OS X 10.9

Comment: Have you try updating IPython ? which version are you using ?

Comment: I added version numbers to the original post. I am using IPython 1.1.0.

Comment: Weird, I cannot reproduce. `;` does silent the output for me. Do you have a custom profile ? Is it pure ipython console (I suppose you use `--pylab`) or something else. Note that 10.9 is doing some weird things with python/numpy/others as some old version are installed by default and can be used instead of the one you installed with pip.

Comment: I'm aware that `;` should silence the output, but it isn't for some reason. I turned on custom profiles, but the only thing I changed from default to is autoload (using the %autoreload extension) on default.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is readline, but it feel weird though. Does it behave the same on qtconsole and/or notebook ? might help to narrow wether it is readline or not.